# How to make cookie auth scheme generate relative login url instead of absolute one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookie-authentication

When ASP.NET Core authentication scheme redirects to Login Page it sends absolute url to the browser.

Is is possible to make this url relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the [`OnRedirectToLogin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttologin?view=aspnetcore-2.2) event to provide your own logic for the redirection process. Here's an example implementation:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(o =>
    {
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
               var relativeRedirectUri = new Uri(ctx.RedirectUri).PathAndQuery;

               context.Response.Headers["Location"] = relativeRedirectUri;
               context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

               return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
       };
   });
```

The `ctx.RedirectUri` property passed in is absolute, so the code above makes a relative copy and uses that instead.

The default implementation that this replaces is a little more involved, as it supports both AJAX requests that return a 401 and non-AJAX requests that perform a redirect. If you need to support both, have a look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L40) and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30), which previously defined the `Location` header used in redirects, specified that the URI had to be absolute. This has since been superseded by [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) in 2014, allowing relative paths in the `Location` header. However, because of the 15 or so years that elapsed in between, an absolute location is still sent to maintain compatibility. Granted, now that we're in almost 2020, I'd imagine the majority of clients would actually support relative locations at this point, but for the time being at least, ASP.NET Core still sends absolute.